# XSLT value of child node issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file which contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<q>sdfsdf</q>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

And I have two XSL files
XSL#1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/title"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And XSL#2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//cd">
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use XSL#1 result is: “Empire Burlesque” but when I use XSL#2 result is: “sdfsdf Empire Burlesque”.  Why does XSL#2 return such value? Is it possible to get value of child node “title” when parent node “cd” is matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read an *XSLT* script, it is not enough to read what has been written.

You have also to know what has **not** been written, but the XSLT procesor
still assumes as the default setting.

In this particular case, you probably forgot (or till now didn't know)
that the default template for elements and the whole document is:

```
<xsl:template match="* | /">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the default template for text and attribute nodes (slightly simplified) is:

```
<xsl:template match="text() | @*">
  <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So e.g. `q` element (and its content) is processed by just these templates,
reproducing **only** the text content and ignoring markup (XML tags).

If you don't want this, add e.g. an empty template matching `q` elements

```
<xsl:template match="q"/>
```

and the extra *sdfsdf* will disappear from the output.

Actually you can put instead an empty template for text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

to "suppress" the text content of all elements which your templates do not serve explicitely.

Comment: Why does XSL#1 work correctly without adding empty template matching?

Comment: Note that your version 1 contains a template matching the **whole** input document (`/`) and this template does not contain any *apply-templates*.
This is why the XSLT processor has no chance to apply any of its default templates.
On the other hand, version 2 contains only a tempate matching "//cd".
So default templates process the whole document, the root element (*catalog*) and other elements (other than `cd`, for which you wrote your own template).